# embedded web/application server

Tags: html, embedded

I need to write an user menu for an embedded device (mips linux). The menu has to be accessible from network (web page - AJAX?) and it has to be able to read/write hardware settings. What would be the easiest way to implement such an app/server? Where do I start?

PS: c/c++ preferred. 
PS 2: I have limited resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) embeddable web server.

See this related page on [writing web applications](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/wiki/WritingWebApplications).

Comment: It was shttpd the last time I used it. Worked great on a Win CE project. Glad it see it has found a new home and name. And now it has language bindings -- sweet!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running linux you could try [thttpd - tiny/turbo/throttling HTTP server](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/)

Answer (score -1):

You may also consider a commercial server such as the Barracuda Server:
http://barracudaserver.com/

Comment: Full disclosure: this is a sock puppet user, spamming links to their company's website. This one remained, but most other users were deleted. I wouldn't consider this an endorsement by any actual SO user.